# How to redirect Matlab output of a command to a file?

Tags: matlab, struct, output

I want to redirect or copy the output of a Matlab command to a file. How can I do that?

In my case, I have two large structs that I want to compare using the UNIX tool `diff`.

Example: I can do this in Matlab:

```
>> s1

s1 = 

      a: 32
    abc: 'example'

>>
```

and want a file containing approx:

```
s1 = 

      a: 32
    abc: 'example'
```

These solutions are not viable:

- Copy-pase: can't automate (comfortably).
- `save -ascii`: does not work with structs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at the [diary function](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-a-diary-file.html). E.g.

```
diary my_file.txt
s1
diary off
```

The file `my_file.txt` will then contain exactly what you see on screen.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do it more fine grained there is the `evalc` function that will store the output to a string.

Later you can output the string into any output channel matlab offers.